# Comparison of two equal arrays fails

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, debugging, comparison

Usually, addressing StackOverflow community I try to describe my problem as well as I know.
But for now it is very hard to tell anything. Just look at the following picture:

[image]

In general, `colors` is changed many times in many ways; while `initial` is constant and it is used to check, whether the current state is equal to initial one (and to cancel all changes, if not).
The question looks easy, but I've stuck with it. How could it be possible, that two equal arrays are not **always equal**?

I don't know what to add without bringing the code of whole project, – so just ask and I will answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in ECMAscript are also just a specialised form of Object. That in turn means, if you compare `array1` with `array2` using `==` or `===` you're comparing effectively two *object references*, not the array itself nor their contents.

Actually, your second approach by `join`ing the arrays and compare that outcome is not bad, if you can guarantee that the contents are always strings. Otherwise you would have to loop the array, compare each value individually and of course also compare the `.length` of those arrays.

Comment: What can be the difference between these two objects? They both are created in one way: `var variableName = value;`. The fact of rewriting the value of the variable is not remembered, as far as I know.

Comment: A reference is just like a pointer in C. It just references an abstract portion of memory (this is just a comparison, not what actually happens, even tho it's quiet close). So you can't directly just compare those two references with equality operators.

Comment: Does it mean, that comparing two arrays is generally bad practice?

Comment: No, not by any means. It just means you have to compare all values "manually" to really have a sufficient comparison. Sloppy solutions which might work are to join the array contents and compare the strings or JSON stringify the Arrays and compare that outcome (which is basically the same, just slightly more accurate).

Comment: Looks like only the primitives can be effectively compared.

Comment: Exactly, that's why you need to compare the contents individually. If there are *Objects* within the arrays you want to compare, you would need to also compare those individually (recursively), which can become slightly tricky, but it would be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript object comparisons (including comparisons between array objects) merely compare the reference values. Two different objects are never equal to each other, no matter what they look like.

You can of course write your own array comparison function based on your own criteria for what it means for one array to be equal to another. If the arrays should contain the same values in the same order to be considered equal, for example, then:

```
function arraysEq(a1, a2) {
  if (a1.length != a2.length) return false;
  for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; ++i)
    if (a1[i] !== a2[i]) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Note that that's just an example; it should not be considered a general solution to the "how do I compare two arrays" problem.

Comment: Works for arrays that don't contain objects or other arrays that need deep comparison.  Can be fooled by an object that has a `.length` property.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes indeed; in general the problem is not at all trivial. In the context of some particular application, however, those issues may not be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

The `==` operator in Javascript does not compare the contents of two arrays or objects.  Instead, it just compares to see if the two arrays or objects are actually the same object.  You can make your own comparison function if you want to see if the two contain the same contents.  One possible way of doing that for arrays that contain strings would be with `.join()`:

```
colors.join("") === initial.join("")
```

This isn't entirely foolproof for all possible array contents, but if you know the array only contains strings and the strings won't contain commas themselves, then this works as a shortcut.  A more robust content comparison can also be written.  For a one level deep comparison of arrays, you can use this:

```
function compareArrays(a, b) {
    if (typeof a.length === "number" && a.length === b.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] !== b[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

For a deep comparison where each array could contain other arrays or objects that you also want to compare the contents of those, then you'd need a recursive solution that could deep compare both object properties and array elements.

You can do a deep comparison of both objects and arrays with something like this:

```
function compareObjects(a, b) {
    // if both are objects, then do a deep comparison of all properties
    if (typeof a === "object" && typeof b === "object") {
        var aKeys = Object.keys(a).sort(), bKeys = Object.keys(b).sort();
        var prop;
        if (!compareArrays(aKeys, bKeys)) {
            return false;
        }
        // here we know the two objects have the same keys, check values now
        for (var i = 0; i < aKeys.length; i++) {
            prop = aKeys[i];
            if (typeof a[prop] === "object" && typeof b[prop] === "object") {
                if (!compareObjects(a[prop], b[prop])) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (a[prop] !== b[prop]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        // not both objects so just do straight equality
        return a === b;
    }
}

function compareArrays(a, b) {
    if (typeof a.length === "number" && a.length === b.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] !== b[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This would allow you to compare nested structures that have objects inside of them and to compare plain objects in addition to arrays like this:

```
var a = {foo: [1,2,3,["a","b","c"]], fee: {a: "1"}};
var b = {fee: {a: "1"}, foo: [1,2,3,4,["a","b","c"]]};
```

Note: This compares publicly enumerable properties of objects or arrays.  It does not compare private (e.g. closure) variables of a custom formed object (say a constructor that creates a closure).  For those, the only way to compare those is with a custom comparison method that can access the private data of the objects themselves.

Note: This does not work for objects or arrays that contain circular references (DOM objects are notorious for circular references).  It is possible to make it work with circular references by keeping a track of all references that are already being compared in an array or Set and not recursing into them again if already in the process of comparing them.

Comment: Added recursive deep comparison.

Answer (score 1):

This is how javascript equal (`==`) operator works:

[image]

and here how the strict equal works (`===`):

[image]

Images from [JavaScript Equality Table](http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/).

Comment: Thank you for help. Your answer just shows the situation, but unfortunately doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Copying other people's work without attribution is [plagiarism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). I have edited your answer to include attribution. Please be sure to include it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In *JavaScript* we have `[] === []; // false` because all *Objects* are tested for equality by their reference, you can see the spec on this [**here**](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6) <sup>*(7)*</sup> and [**here**](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) <sup>*(1.f)*</sup>.

You could write a function to do the test you want using [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
function equivArray(a, b) {
    return a.length === b.length && a.every(function (e, i) {return e === b[i];});
}
```

Now

```
var foo = ['a', 'b', 1, 2],
    bar = ['a', 'b', 1, 2];

equivArray(foo, bar); // true
```